# Descendants not found even if they exist in XDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am having problems with getting descendant with specific name. I have hugh XML that basically is made of lots of this elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Search_Results xmlns="https://support.bridgerinsight.lexisnexis.com/downloads/xsd/4.5/OutputFile.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://support.bridgerinsight.lexisnexis.com/downloads/xsd/4.5/OutputFile.xsd https://support.bridgerinsight.lexisnexis.com/downloads/xsd/4.5/OutputFile.xsd">
<Entity Record="28" ResultID="12460985">
    <GeneralInfo>
        <EntityType>Individual</EntityType>
        <Name>Jón Jónsson</Name>
        <DOB>01/01/0001</DOB>
        <DOBParsed />
        <AccountID>ABS-ASSOC-10-109</AccountID>
        <IDLabel>Account ID</IDLabel>
        <IDNumber>ABS-ASSOC-10-109</IDNumber>
        <AddressType>Current</AddressType>
        <PostalCode>Somalia</PostalCode>
    </GeneralInfo>
    <RecordDetailInfo>
        <EntityType>Individual</EntityType>
        <SearchDate>2016-05-13 09:53:50Z</SearchDate>
        <Origin>Automatic Batch</Origin>
        <FirstName>Jón</FirstName>
        <LastName>Jónsson</LastName>
        <FullName>Jón Jónsson</FullName>
        <AdditionalInfo>
            <Type>Date of Birth</Type>
            <Information>01/01/0001</Information>
        </AdditionalInfo>
        <Addresses>
            <Type>Current</Type>
            <PostalCode>Somalia</PostalCode>
        </Addresses>
        <Identifications>
            <Type>Account ID</Type>
            <Number>ABS10-109</Number>
        </Identifications>
    </RecordDetailInfo>
    <WatchList>
        <Match ID="1">
            <EntityName>Jonsson</EntityName>
            <EntityScore>96</EntityScore>
            <BestName>Jonsson, Jon Orn</BestName>
            <BestNameScore>96</BestNameScore>
            <FileName>WorldCompliance - Full.BDF</FileName>
            <SourceDate>2016-05-11 05:01:00Z</SourceDate>
            <DistributionDate>2016-05-12 14:59:39Z</DistributionDate>
            <ResultDate>2016-05-13 09:53:50Z</ResultDate>
            <EntityUniqueID>WX0003219444</EntityUniqueID>
            <MatchDetails>
                <Entity Type="2">
                    <Number>3219444</Number>
                    <Date>9/3/2012</Date>
                    <Reason>International</Reason>
                    <CheckSum>69185</CheckSum>
                    <Gender>Male</Gender>
                    <Name>
                        <First>Jon Orn</First>
                        <Last>Jonsson</Last>
                        <Full>Jon Orn Jonsson</Full>
                    </Name>
                    <Notes>Source.</Notes>
                    <Addresses>
                        <Address ID="1" Type="4">
                            <Country>Iceland</Country>
                        </Address>
                    </Addresses>
                    <IDs>
                        <ID ID="1" Type="27">
                            <Number>3219444</Number>
                        </ID>
                    </IDs>
                    <Descriptions>
                        <Description ID="1" Type="10">
                            <Value>Honorary Consul of Iceland in Saskatchewan, Canada</Value>
                            <Notes>Starting 2002 Ending 2014</Notes>
                        </Description>
                        <Description ID="2" Type="22">
                            <Value>Link to WorldCompliance Online Database</Value>
                            <Notes>Jonsson, Jon Orn | https://members.worldcompliance.com/metawatch2.aspx?id=e0399c29-7c5e-4674-874c-f36fdb19052e</Notes>
                        </Description>
                        <Description ID="3" Type="22">
                            <Value>Sources of Record Information</Value>
                            <Notes>http://brunnur.mfa.is/interpro/utanr/HBvefur.nsf/Pages/IslSendiradIsl?OpenDocument&amp;amp | CountryNr=1(Canada)&amp;amp | Lang=44') | http://www.international.gc.ca/protocol-protocole/assets/pdfs/Diplomatic_List.pdf | http://www.inlofna.org/Elfros/newsletter%20January%202010.pdf | http://publications.gc.ca/collections/Collection/E12-3-2002E.pdf | http://www.onlygolfnews.com/golf-canada-saskatchewan/saskatchewan-golf-first-fort-lacrosse-ted-brandon-over-new-last-snow.htm | http://www.ops.gov.sk.ca/Consular-Officers</Notes>
                        </Description>
                    </Descriptions>
                </Entity>
            </MatchDetails>
        </Match>
    </WatchList>
</Entity>
</Search_Results>
```

I am trying to reach all elements with name: Entity and later I want to go through all of them and get values from their descendants with name "Reason".
But non of the Entity elements is found with this line:

```
var entityList = xmlDoc.Descendants(nameSpace + "Entity").ToList();
```

This is a whole method I am using:

```
public static void GetIBANAndBicValuesFromXML(XDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        var reasons = new List<string>();
        XNamespace nameSpace =
            "https://support.bridgerinsight.lexisnexis.com/downloads/xsd/4.5/";

        var entityList = xmlDoc.Descendants(nameSpace + "Entity").ToList();

        if (entityList != null)
        {
            foreach (var reason in entityList.Select(entity => entity.Elements(nameSpace + "Reason"))
                .Where(reasonsList => reasonsList != null).SelectMany(reasonsList => reasonsList))
            {
                string reasonValue = reason.Value;
                reasons.Add(reasonValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is a call to this method:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xmlFile = "C:\\temp\\indi2.xml";
    var x = XDocument.Load("C:\\temp\\Individuals.xml");

    XMLParse.GetIBANAndBicValuesFromXML(x);
}
```

I have tried namespace like this as well:

```
"https://support.bridgerinsight.lexisnexis.com/downloads/xsd/4.5/OutputFile.xsd"
```

But no success.
Anybody sees what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but just wanted to confirm that using the (https://support.bridgerinsight.lexisnexis.com/downloads/xsd/4.5/OutputFile.xsd) returns the 2 entity nodes as expected when I test this!

Comment: If I put your given XML into a document and use the correct namespace (`https://support.bridgerinsight.lexisnexis.com/downloads/xsd/4.5/OutputFile.xsd`) I get 2 items in entityList. You may need to verify that your xml is coming in correctly or that its not something else later causing you to lose the data. Running the rest of that method does pull out a single reason (`International`).

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].  Per the two comments above, this works, so there's not a lot to answer.  As an aside, none of the things you're checking for null could *ever* be null.  Your code could be reduced to `var reasons = xmlDoc.Descendants(nameSpace + "Reason").Select(x => x.Value).ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to filter with LocalName:

```
string fileName = "1.txt";
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var neededElements = xDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Entity");
Console.WriteLine("Found {0} Entitys", neededElements.Count());
foreach(var el in neededElements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(el);
}
```